# How to apply Inheritance to Generics in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

I have a generic Container struct that is stored as a container of a class that implements a protocol as below:

```
protocol Protocol {}
class Class : Protocol {}
struct Container<Element> {
    var value:Element
    init(_ v:Element) { value = v }
}
class Example {
    var container : Container<Class>
    init() { container = Container(Class()) }
    func getContainer() -> Container<Protocol> { return container }
}
```

However when I pass it I want to pass it as a Container of just the protocol which is generating an error on `return container`:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Container<Class>' to return type 'Container<Protocol>'
```

I know this should be possible as Swift does it with arrays as below:

```
class ArrayExample {
    var arrayContainer : [Class]
    init() { arrayContainer = [Class()] }
    func getArrayContainer() -> [Protocol] { return arrayContainer }
}
```

So does anyone have any thoughts on how to implement Container so that the conversion/copy doesn't create the error

Comment: But you can't declare `container` as `var container : Container<Protocol>`?

Comment: I could declare the container as Container<Protocol> but Inside the class I want access to variable/functions that aren't in the protocol

Comment: And you can't cast down to the class there in order to access those variable/functions?

Comment: Theoretically I could but I dislike casting down when I can avoid it as a coding style preference.  I'm not looking for a work around I'm looking how to implement functionality that swift alows as evident in the arrayContainer example.

Comment: Despite what you've called it, `Protocol` is not a protocol - it's a class, and your `Class` is a subclass of it.

Comment: Ops fixed it in the example.  Checked it against the playground and the difference didn't affect the problem

Comment: Well, the thing is that, as you've already discovered, casting of generics doesn't work the way you want. You can substitute Container<Class> where a Container<Protocol> is expected — that is why your initializer works — but you cannot cast between a Container<Protocol> and a Container<Class>. As I've already said, I don't understand what you _really_ want to do, so all I can do is try to take your specifications on board as you list them. If you don't like the way they have to be accomplished, maybe you should change your desires.

Comment: Then why can I cast the array which is also a generic?

Comment: Because when you cast an array you get a new array formed by casting every single one of the elements. Array-casting is special syntactic sugar. There is actually no such thing; it's an illusion.

Comment: Okay I buy that it only work for structs because struct are passed by copying.  However even after changing Container to a struct I get the same error.  So how do I implement a copy constructor that allows for the change as I doubt that it is something that apple only allows for Arrays (if it is please link documentation that supports that assertion)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what you're actually trying to accomplish, but here's code that compiles and that covers all the goals you've expressed so far:

```
protocol Protocol {}
class Class : Protocol {
    var thing : AnyObject?
}
class Container<Element> {
    var value:Element
    init(_ v:Element) { value = v }
}
class Example {
    var container : Container<Protocol>
    init() { container = Container(Class()) }
    func getContainer() -> Container<Protocol> { return container }
    func doStuff() {
        if let v = container.value as? Class { v.thing = "ha" }
    }
}
```